# how to vertical align a span and a div in the same row

Tags: css

I have multiple rows of texts and divs like this:

```
<div>
  <span>Adeline</span><div style="display:inline; height:20px, width:20px, background-color: blue">hi</div>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Ted</span><div style="display:inline; height:20px, width:20px, background-color: green">hi</div>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Sara</span><div style="display:inline; height:20px, width:20px, background-color: coral">hi</div>
</div>
```

How can I make sure in each row the span and the div are vertically aligned?

Comment: Why are you using `div` and setting the style to `display: inline`? Use `span` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have u tried  `vertical-align: middle` this work for inline elements! add it for your span and div

Answer (score 1):

Inline elements will all appear on the same line by default. Though, you can change their position with the `vertical-align:` property which takes 1 of 5 arguments: baseline, text-top, text-bottom, sub, and super.
I see in your example you are applying height and width to the div, for this to work you must first apply the `display: inline-block` property. This lets you resize inline elements.
Hope this helps.